# compile package python-lightblue from source

Tags: raspbian

i want install `lightblue` module for python in `raspberry`

this is homepage http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/#downloads

when i want to install python module via `sudo python setup.py install`

error appear :

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_lightblueutil' extension
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/linux/lightblue_util.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-2.7/src/linux/lightblue_util.o
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-fstack-protector-strong'
error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

how can i install this in raspberry ?

latest version module not available in pypi and apt-get and i must install it from source

Comment: Have you seen the [GitHub](https://github.com/Hexxeh/libpebble/blob/master/README.md) `git clone https://github.com/pebble/lightblue-0.4` might be worth a go

Comment: I used git version and I tried it. At first I got error about python.h so I installed python-dev. Tried again and I get error about no Bluetooth. I don't have it, so that as far as I can go, but this was on Raspbian and I'm not getting the errors you are, so try git version. Also make sure build-essential is installed

Comment: @geoffmcc same error in git ....
i use python 2.7.8 ... maybe this is the issue ...

Comment: Just checked, I'm on 2.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the exact same error as you when I tried to install the LightBlue package. However a very simple Google search led me to the solution for the problem. This error is raised when you don't have python-dev installed.

So just use `sudo apt-get install python-dev`, get the developer package installed and recompile. Hoping this works for you. :)